# ¿Input Date compatible con Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, internet-explorer

Tengo un formulario en Html utilizando bootstrap, en todos los navegadores me funciona el input type: "date" solo Internet Explorer no y necesito que sea compatible con ese navegador, encontré una forma de hacerla con Script el cual es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var datefield=document.createElement("input")
datefield.setAttribute("type", "date")
if (datefield.type!="date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
    document.write('<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n')
    document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>\n')
    document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n') 
}
</script>

<script>
if (datefield.type!="date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
jQuery(function($){ //on document.ready
    $('#fecha').datepicker();
    })
}
</script>

<form>
    <b>Fecha:</b>
    <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" size="20" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="B1"></p>
</form>
```

Pero en la base de datos me guarda la fecha en 0000-00-00
Saben a que se debe? (En los demas navegadores me guarda la fecha correcto)

Comment: ¿Con cuál versión de Internet Explorer quieres hacer compatible tu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy buenas.
Me parece que al investigar tu caso de input type, no es compatible con Internet Explorer 11 y versiones recientes. Según revisé la información en w3schools: [Input Type Informacion en inglés](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

En mi caso recomiendo tratar poner por ahora en text, utilizando el formato PHP, aunque imagino que estas utilizando el formato date en una tabla del base de datos, este es el código:

```
<input type="text" name="nombredelinput" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago'); echo date('Y-m-d');?>"><br/>
```

El date_default_timezone_set toma el calendario actual (puedes cambiar el parentesis, sea ('Europe/Madrid') dependiendo del país y la ciudad) y el echo se revela en qué fecha estamos hoy día. Funciona para todos los navegadores, recuerda que el input date solo funciona en otras navegadores (en caso de Html) 
Espero que te haya ayudado, un saludo!